# ionic 3 sqlite - How to execute requests from files

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

I am currently developing a mobile app with ionic. On this application there is a local sqlite database.

I am looking to be able to execute queries from files for possible updates of the database.

For example, when you first install the application, the tables are created if they do not exist. If changes are made to these tables after installing the application, the changes are not taken into account.

I would like to create files which can be executed one by one according to PRAGMA user_version.

Something like :

```
// Get pragma user version, if it's undefined, it's set to 1.
// If user_version < 1, we execute the sql file, then we update the user_version 
// to 1.
db.executeSql(`PRAGMA user_version;`, []).then((res)=> {
    if(res.rows.item(0).user_version < 1) {
          db.sqlBatch(`app/sqlFiles/1.sql`, []).then((res)=>{
              console.log(res);
          }, (err) => {
              console.log("Error : " + JSON.stringify(err));
          });
          db.executeSql(`PRAGMA user_version = 1;`, []).then((res)=>{
              console.log(res);
          }, (err) => {
              console.log("Error : " + JSON.stringify(err));
          });
        }
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("Error : " + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
```

I thought about using a file reader but the file is not found during the execution of the function.

```
this.fileOpener.open('assets/SQLFile/1.sql', 'text/plain')
    .then((file) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("read success");
            console.log(evt.target);
        };

        db.sqlBatch(reader.readAsText(file)).then((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Error : " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });

        console.log('File is opened');
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
```

Will anyone have an idea for doing this kind of thing? (I am looking for a solution that respects good programming practices).

Please note that I am a beginner with ionic and sqlite
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

But you're getting an error or what? Since the post seems to be valid but the implementation seems to be a little off.
After reading the file, storing the content into a variable, you should execute that "sql query" as usually.
Nevertheless it's not a secure way of do that.

When something in your app change due to an update or upgrade, wouldn't be easier and safer to specify that into the code instead of a single file containing all the database info and scheme?

Edited:

If you want to add custom files to deployment, check this out https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/app-scripts/

Comment: For the file reader, the problem is that the file is not found by the file opener. on this command: (I tried several path but FILE NOT FOUND error each time)

this.fileOpener.open ('assets / SQLFile / 1.sql', 'text / plain')

I wont have all the shema in one file. I would like to create a file whenever a modification of the database is necessary (for example I have a table that lists tasks with default insertions.They are inserted when the database is created. to add other tasks by default, I would like to be able to simply execute a query which will be in a separate file)

Comment: The problem of putting everything directly in the code is that I find that it will not necessarily be very clear and in the long run the file may be very large. This would also allow you to have a good history of each change made on the base as well as to see who made the changes by looking at the author of the file.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but that seems like a really bad way for who makes what in a software/application.
Have you tried to put the file in the same path of the file.ts and check if you can access through there?
it may be related to not having the sql file where you think it is in the final app, when it's executed in the device.

Comment: Yes of course you can just look at the annotations on the file to see who added or modified a line. but I think it's a plus to see the change history.

Yes I created a DBModifications folder in the component and access it in this way:
this.fileOpener.open ('./DBModifications/1.sql', 'text / plain')
But without success.

In fact, the problem is that I dont know where to find the file when it runs in the device.

Thank you for your help

Comment: That code is in the home.ts? If that's so, the path is wrong.

Comment: that code is in app.component.ts and DBModifications folder too.

Comment: I already edited my answer: Check this out, it will solve your problems https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/app-scripts/